# Playlist only has first letter of given name

Tags: c#, libspotify

I'm creating a Spotify client using C# and LibspotifyDotNet for accessibility purposes.

I'm implementing a method that will create a new playlist in the user's default session container with the given name. It works, sort of. Except the playlist always has its name set to the first letter I entered, rather than the whole string.

Here is the code I'm using

```
public IntPtr CreateNewPlaylist(string name)
{
    IntPtr namePointer = IntPtr.Zero;
    try
    {
        var sessionContainerPointer = libspotify.sp_session_playlistcontainer(GetSession());
        namePointer = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(name);
        var newPointer = libspotify.sp_playlistcontainer_add_new_playlist(sessionContainerPointer, namePointer);
        return newPointer;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (namePointer != IntPtr.Zero)
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(namePointer);
    }
}
```

I have verified that namePointer does indeed point to the whole string by turning it back into a string to see what it returns. We're all good there.

Am I missing something obvious here? Or is this a LibspotifyDotNet problem? Or a Libspotify one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# stores strings as two bytes per string in memory, so for normal 0-127 ascii values, like say "ABC" it will have a pattern of 0x41,0x00,0x42,0x00,0x43,0x00 in memory.

The [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/docs/libspotify/12.1.51/group__playlist.html) for libspotify shows that `sp_playlistcontainer_add_new_playlist` takes a `const char*` as its second argument.

So the spotify lib is seeing the first byte of the two byte character as the first letter of the string you're sending it, then it's seeing the second byte of the unicode char, which is 0x00.  Since it thinks it's dealing with a single byte string and C ends strings with a 0x00, it processes that as the end of the string.

Try encoding your string to a single char string in a byte array using [ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/595a8te7(v=vs.110).aspx) before you pass it to the api.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So are you saying use Encoding.X.GetBytes to get the byte array and copy that into memory and use that pointer? I'd have thought that would have been how the StringToHGlobalUni worked, but I guess not then.

Comment: Yes, use ASCIIEncoding or UTF8Encoding.  StringToHGlobalUni just allocates an unmanaged buffer and copies the string's data into it.